# How to order data sent to server?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, socket.io, network-programming, server

Ive been making a socketio server for realtime unity games just because and I encountered a problem.

In my game each client objects tell the server their state with a simple struct with a couple a fields , nothing big and the server then broadcasts it to the rest of the clients.

Since I use redis behind all clusters I had to check on a timestamp I sent with each packet to be sure Im not overwriting updates with old data from another client that happened to arrive a little late.

Doing this did improve the problem but still theres something wrong with the way im doing things as it doesnt work as intended (some updates are positions) and , for example, with an object falling , the object goes back up a little every couple of frames. I can tell what the problem is but I dont really know how to fix it.

How do I take in to account that if an object is falling no to take data that positions it above the position in the previous packet without making handlers for each physics event and input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: you are asking about the incredibly difficult topic of "predictive" networking, for realtime games.  whole buildings of mathematicians and researchers work on this for race game titles and the like.  you can google a little, example  http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/329595/view.html

Comment: while a good question, since it is general you'd want to ask on gamedev.com or similar